# I am trying to show the data from my ajax response to my jquery data table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, datatable

What I am trying to do it that I am trying to show my ajax response to my jquery data table
my table looks like this

```
<div style="margin: 20px;">

                                            <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Spouse</th>
                                                        <th>CNIC</th>
                                                        <th>Father</th>
                                                        <th>Mother.</th>
                                                        <th>Employee ID</th>
                                                        <th>Children</th>
                                                        <th>Age</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                            </table>
                                                </div>
```

and below is my ajax response which I am trying to show in my table but its not showing any data yet I am getting data from this link in my postman.
my ajax call is written below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
      ajax: {
        url : "https://2057-185-202-239-227.ngrok.io/employee/employeesByCompany/"+sessionStorage.getItem('Companies_id'),
        dataSrc: "doc",
      },
      columns: [
        { data: 'spouse' },
        { data: 'CNIC' },
        { data: 'fatherName' },
        { data: 'motherName' },
        { data: 'employeeID' },
        { data: 'age' },
        { data: 'children[]' }
      ],
    });
  });

    </script>
```

here is my Json Response which I am getting and I want to add pagination on

```
{
"message": "Success",
"doc": [
    {
        "createdDate": "2022-04-03T17:19:02.666Z",
        "enabled": true,
        "_id": "6249d7156a4ef003db97e4bd",
        "fName": "James Bartley",
        "age": 30,
        "CNIC": "3974224221510",
        "spouse": "Hilary",
        "fatherName": "James",
        "motherName": "Brunhilde",
        "employeeImage": "http://dummyimage.com/267x237.png/ff4444/ffffff",
        "employeeID": "IN319122",
        "company": "62498fc7acd7fb091185bb0e",
        "children": [],
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "createdDate": "2022-04-03T17:19:02.666Z",
        "enabled": true,
        "_id": "6249d7156a4ef003db97e4c2",
        "fName": "Clerc Billings",
        "age": 52,
        "CNIC": "4618981270977",
        "spouse": "Debra",
        "fatherName": "Clerc",
        "motherName": "Gwendolyn",
        "employeeImage": "http://dummyimage.com/258x287.png/cc0000/ffffff",
        "employeeID": "IN313190",
        "company": "62498fc7acd7fb091185bb0e",
        "children": [],
        "__v": 0
    },
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use `success` in a DataTables `ajax` option - see the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc): "_the success option of ajax should not be altered - DataTables uses it internally to execute the table draw when the data load is complete._"

Comment: Also, if your JSON is suitably structured, there should be no need to build strings of HTML data. DataTables can consume JSON directly. Look at the [various Ajax data source examples](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/index.html). In fact, building HTML strings won't work anyway, as DataTables knows nothing about this data.

Comment: Final note: The `columns` option refers to `doc` - but that is not a valid DataTables column option. Again, look at the official DataTables examples and also the many questions and answers on this site. Start with something as simple as possible which works, and build from there.

Comment: can you edit the code? @andrewJames

Comment: Please edit your question to show the text of your JSON response. And are you not able to use the official examples to help you? They are simple and are a great place to start.

Comment: @andrewJames I have placed my Json response which I am getting

Comment: @andrewJames I have used office example but its not working can you help me out PLEASE..!

Comment: Saying "it is not working" does not really help. Your JSON does help, however - so thank you for that. Take a look at the approach in my answer. If something is not clear then let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach which uses your JSON.

The table:

```html
<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Spouse</th>
                <th>CNIC</th>
                <th>Father</th>
                <th>Mother.</th>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
      ajax: {
        url : "http://localhost:7001/docdata",
        dataSrc: "doc"
      },
      columns: [
        { data: "spouse" },
        { data: "CNIC" },
        { data: "fatherName" },
        { data: "motherName" },
        { data: "employeeID" },
        { data: "age" }            
      ]
    } );
  });
```

My URL returns your JSON. Because your JSON's data array is called `doc`, you need to use that name in the `dataSrc` option:

```
dataSrc: "doc"
```

There is no need to manipulate any HTML strings.

You should be able to take this and add in the extra pieces you may need - such as your URL, your use of session storage, and so on.

My example generates the following:

[image]

Comment: my URL uses GET request do I have to pass it here?

Comment: Can you not try this for yourself? Try without using `"type" : "GET"` - and try _with_ using `"type" : "GET"`. What happens in each case?

Comment: Then also take a look at the documentation for [jQuery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Scroll down to the `type` parameter and see what it says - especially see what the default value is.

Comment: Hey i am having an error which is cannot read the properties of undefined (reading 'length')

can you help with that? @andrewJames

Comment: I have no idea what your new code looks like. I have provided a working solution, where (as the first step you should take) the only thing you needed to change from my code was the URL. Did you do that? Otherwise, take a look at how to provide a [mre].

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. I edited your code according to myself and it worked for me. I have one issue its not getting age data it says Unknown parameter age. What could be the possible fix for this?

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'age' for row 0, column 2. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

it throws this error @andrewJames

Comment: I am glad you have something which (almost) works. But just to say again, I cannot tell you why `age` is not working because I cannot see your updated code. Please edit your question and add a [mre] which allows us to recreate the issue you are having.

Comment: Thanks to you sir.

I updated my code and posted it above its not reading age idont know why.
And  I appended my children column as well and its showing object I try to use map on it but idont know how to write in proper syntax of jquery datatable.

Comment: Your HTML table has 6 `<th>` headings. Your DataTable is trying to create 7 `column` values. That will cause a problem. I don't know if that will fix your error. But it needs to be corrected, for sure.

Comment: I tried but it didnt worked out :) .
Sorry to disturb you alot,

Comment: The age is available but its not finding it idont know why

Comment: Show your updated code.

Comment: I updated the code in question :)

Comment: The code in your question works correctly for me (except your last 2 headings are the wrong way round). There must be something else you are not showing us. Try to create a MRE (emphasis on the "R" for "reproducible").

Answer (score 0):

If you mean this:

```
doc.map(function(item, id) {
  return(
    <tr key={id}>
      <td>{item.fatherName}</td>
      <td>{item.motherName}</td>
      <td>{item.spouse}</td>
    </tr>
  )
}.bind(this))
```

Comment: where to put this ?

Comment: In ajax -> success have response try console.log and watch for it and after foexample try response.fatherName , after u understand this will show u next step

Or you can try to put .map() in <script>

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.